# Como saber se a opção de "animações do Windows" estão desabilitadas no Win32?

Tags: windows, golang, winapi

No CSS existe o [`prefers-reduced-motion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion). Essa media-query diz que o usuário prefere animações reduzidas (desligadas) ou não, ela respeita a configuração que o usuário escolheu nas configurações do Windows (ou outro sistema operacional):

> In Windows 10: Settings > Ease of Access > Display > Show animations in Windows.

---

Como posso obter a mesma informação (saber se as animações estão desligadas ou não) nativamente? Como que os navegador, em si, conseguem identificar se tal recurso está desligado?

Existe algum [WindowProc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v=vs.85)) quando essa configuração é alterada?

---

*Para maiores detalhes: Estou criando uma janela do Windows usando o `user32.dll` (`CreateWindowExW`), e então desenhando ela com o OpenGL. Estou usando Golang, chamando a DLL via [`syscall.NewLazySystemDLL`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#NewLazySystemDLL). Preciso saber quando as animações estão desligadas para que o comportamento do aplicativo no Windows e no navegador sejam idênticos.*

Comment: Isso provavelmente fica gravado no registro do Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

const (
    SPI_GETCLIENTAREAANIMATION = 0x1042
)

var (
    user32DLL            = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    systemParametersInfo = user32DLL.NewProc("SystemParametersInfoW")
)

func main() {
    var enabled bool
    _, _, err := systemParametersInfo.Call(uintptr(SPI_GETCLIENTAREAANIMATION), 0, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&enabled)), 0)
    if err != syscall.Errno(0) {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(enabled)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/vGlfqpcGgLJ

Lembrando que você deve tratar os erros corretamente, como você já está usando o pacote syscall e unsafe, obviamente tem experiência com isso.

Para testar o comportamento, pode alterar a configuração do Windows em Propriedades do sistema -> Desempenho -> Configurações

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]